# Prisma query upsert

Tags: javascript, postgresql, prisma, upsert

How can I do this query in prisma:

```
    INSERT INTO user_conference (user_id, conference_id, points, activities_completed)
    VALUES (1, '3a4QQI0KbO0eaDjzhIgeeZ', 40, ARRAY ['4vwp3L1EJYQ9rI1Pv7er2'])
    ON CONFLICT (user_id, conference_id) DO UPDATE
    SET points = user_conference.points + 40, 
    activities_completed = user_conference.activities_completed || '4vwp3L1EJYQ9rI1Pv7c4x0'::text
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a late answer, but it could help others.

The way I see it, on Postgres **ON CONFLICT** expect a **unique field** or a combination of fields with **unique constraints**. This goes the same for PRISMA.

On your Prisma model

```
model user_conference {
   user_id Int
   conference_id String
   points Int
   activities_completed String[]
   @@unique([user_id, conference_id])
 }
```

For your direct query translation, use this.

```js
prisma.user_conference.upsert({
   where: {
     user_id_conference_id : { // here Prisma expects user_id and conference_id both in combination are unique
       user_id: 1,
       conference_id: '3a4QQI0KbO0eaDjzhIgeeZ',
     }
   },
   create: {
     user_id: 1,
     conference_id: '3a4QQI0KbO0eaDjzhIgeeZ',
     points: 40,
     activities_completed: ['4vwp3L1EJYQ9rI1Pv7er2']
   },
   update: {
     points: {
       increment: 40,
     },
     activities_completed: {
       push: '4vwp3L1EJYQ9rI1Pv7c4x0'
     }
   }
 });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply I end up doing a raw query in the meantime ... gonna test this :)